# Firebase firestore: "error: InjectProcessingStep was unable to process"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I was recommended on my previous post by a community member regarding the use of firebase firestore database to download an app called make-it-so that uses firestore database, in order to learn how it works. I have tried a few times to make the app work but I keep on getting this error, any idea why? Any help is much appreciated!

Error message: https://gyazo.com/8b8d41eddc9b176c376b3e98c2c249e7

```
error: InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'AccountServiceImpl(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)' because 'User' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.model.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl
      => element (METHOD): getCurrentUser()
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): ()kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<User>
      => type (DECLARED return type): kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<User>
      => type (ERROR type argument): User
  
  If type 'User' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'User' is on your classpath.
error: InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'SplashViewModel(ConfigurationService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.AccountService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.LogService)' because 'ConfigurationService' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.screens.splash.SplashViewModel
      => element (CONSTRUCTOR): SplashViewModel(ConfigurationService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.AccountService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.LogService)
      => type (EXECUTABLE constructor): (ConfigurationService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.AccountService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.LogService)void
      => type (ERROR parameter type): ConfigurationService
  
  If type 'ConfigurationService' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'ConfigurationService' is on your classpath.
error: InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'TasksViewModel(com.example.makeitso.model.service.LogService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.StorageService,ConfigurationService)' because 'ConfigurationService' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.screens.tasks.TasksViewModel
      => element (FIELD): configurationService
      => type (ERROR field): ConfigurationService
  
  If type 'ConfigurationService' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'ConfigurationService' is on your classpath.
error: ModuleProcessingStep was unable to process 'com.example.makeitso.model.service.module.ServiceModule' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.
  
InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'AccountServiceImpl(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)' because 'User' could not be resolved.

  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.model.service.module.ServiceModule
      => element (METHOD): provideConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceImpl)
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): (ConfigurationServiceImpl)ConfigurationService
      => type (ERROR parameter type): ConfigurationServiceImpl
  
  If type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is on your classpath.
error: BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideAccountService(com.example.makeitso.model.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.model.service.module.ServiceModule
      => element (METHOD): provideConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceImpl)
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): (ConfigurationServiceImpl)ConfigurationService
      => type (ERROR parameter type): ConfigurationServiceImpl
  
  If type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is on your classpath.
error: BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideLogService(com.example.makeitso.model.service.impl.LogServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.model.service.module.ServiceModule
      => element (METHOD): provideConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceImpl)
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): (ConfigurationServiceImpl)ConfigurationService
      => type (ERROR parameter type): ConfigurationServiceImpl
  
  If type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is on your classpath.
error: BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideStorageService(com.example.makeitso.model.service.impl.StorageServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.model.service.module.ServiceModule
      => element (METHOD): provideConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceImpl)
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): (ConfigurationServiceImpl)ConfigurationService
      => type (ERROR parameter type): ConfigurationServiceImpl
  
  If type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is on your classpath.
error: BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.example.makeitso.model.service.module.ServiceModule
      => element (METHOD): provideConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceImpl)
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): (ConfigurationServiceImpl)ConfigurationService
      => type (ERROR parameter type): ConfigurationServiceImpl
  
  If type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' is on your classpath.
InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'SplashViewModel(ConfigurationService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.AccountService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.LogService)' because 'ConfigurationService' could not be resolved.

InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'TasksViewModel(com.example.makeitso.model.service.LogService,com.example.makeitso.model.service.StorageService,ConfigurationService)' because 'ConfigurationService' could not be resolved.

ModuleProcessingStep was unable to process 'com.example.makeitso.model.service.module.ServiceModule' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.

BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideAccountService(com.example.makeitso.model.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.

BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideLogService(com.example.makeitso.model.service.impl.LogServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.

BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideStorageService(com.example.makeitso.model.service.impl.StorageServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.

BindingMethodProcessingStep was unable to process 'provideConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceImpl)' because 'ConfigurationServiceImpl' could not be resolved.


> Task :app:kaptDevDebugKotlin FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: If you want to learn how to create a simple app using Firestore and Jetpack Compose, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp). Or you might be interested in reading this [series](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-firebase-part-1-4f305485e5d2).

Comment: Thank you very much! The resource, repo and series are really helpful, now I can dive deep into learning firestore :) Much appreciated! Also, keep up the YT videos so I can continue to learn from there as well! :)@Alex Mamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering as Community wiki, As mentioned by Alex Mamo in above comments.

If you want to learn how to create a simple app using Firestore and Jetpack Compose, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp). Or you might be interested in reading this [series](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-firebase-part-1-4f305485e5d2).

You can refer to these [Link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDKAMU6xV9s) and [Link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvQ4vH2dC78) which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

go in the project bar and change android view to project

[image]

once done check if the google-services.json file exixt if it not there ask for it to the owner project and then it will work

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I had already set up a project in firebase containing firestore, auth and realtime database. When I downloaded this kotlin project I added the j-son file as standard (as you described above already) and connected the the SHA-1 key to the respective project. The problem happens later when I run the project, this error then occur @Josue Muleshi